# Have a list of tuples with strings, want to turn into a single string in Python

Tags: python

I have a data structure that looks like `[("hello", 12), ("yo", 30)]`. How do I combine all of the 0th position of each tuple into a string? The output of the above would be like: `"helloyo"`.
Here is what I've tried:

```
' '.join[tuple[0] for tuple in tuples]
```

Comment: `''.join` instead of `' '.join`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nearly there, this will work:

```
''.join(t[0] for t in tuples)
```

BTW, don't use `tuple` as a variable, as it's also a python type.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
d = [("hello", 12), ("yo", 30)]
' '.join( [ t[ 0 ] for t in d ] )

#output
'hello yo'
```

or if you don't want spaces:

```
d = [("hello", 12), ("yo", 30)]
''.join( [ t[ 0 ] for t in d ] )

#output
'helloyo'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've got almost works, except `xxx.join` joins the arguments with `xxx` as the separator, and since `join` is a function, it needs brackets around it.

So if you want `'helloyo'`, just do:

```
''.join([tuple[0] for tuple in tuples])
```

In fact, for `join`, you don't even need the list comprehension:

```
''.join(tuple[0] for tuple in tuples)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but `join` is a function, so you need ( ), not [ ]

Answer (score 0):

`join` is a method if strings. You're using `[]`, you want `''.join()`.